How to limit Start Menu item for MSIX to just the UI app?
I have a Windows Application Packaging project with a UI app and a console app.
It builds and installs fine (see my previous post). One thing I'd like to change is that the console app ideally shouldn't appear in the Start menu after installation - the console app always takes arguments and makes no sense to launch without them.
How would I modify the Package.appxmanifest to prevent including the console app in the start menu?

Found the solution:
Just had to add the following to the uap:VisualElements section of the console Application section of the Package.appxmanifest file:
AppListEntry="none"

